# What should our next blog post be about?

Tags: discussion, community-blog

I posted our most recent blog post ( [How to Make the most out of Ramadan](http://islam.blogoverflow.com/2013/07/how-to-make-the-most-out-of-ramadan/) ), posted on July 16th.  Insha'Allah our next post will be posted on this month (August) on the 15th, a Thursday.  What would need to be discussed is what the post would be about, and who would be writing it.  If no one is available to write it, then I should write it myself Insha'Allah.  I haven't gotten the contributors who wish to be among those who write posts that organized yet, for they are few, and many of the contributors are among the category: (Editors).

So if anyone would like to contribute to writing a post then please come visit the [blog chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8205/islam-ses-blog-chatroom) and talk to me.  Currently we need to discuss what the subject of the post would be, it could be about Jihad, something about Da'wah, something about a Surah etc.  Simply give your suggestions under this post so we can discuss them and so that they can be voted on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think an article on the basics of da'wah would be very useful, especially on how it should (and shouldn't) be done.  As opposed to the common "prove Islam is right/prove everyone else is wrong" model; debate has it's place and value, but it's incorrect to call it *da'wah*.

Comment: That's a great suggestion, looking forward to an article on this.

Answer (score 0):

A blog post about Jihad, It doesn't have to big long, simply goes through what jihad is, and the Ummah's need for it in today's world.

Comment: good, But Which Jihad , you should specifically write about the warfare Jihad.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to write a post on "An Analysis of Bani Israel Vs Jews in the Quran: A linguistic analysis on why the Bani Israel were not Jews"

Comment: What's the connection to Islam other than using the Qur'an as an input?  Does Islam care about what Jews call themselves?

Comment: @MonicaCellio God chose the nation of Bani Israel to deliver few of its early messages, thousands of years later some people can't claim to be Bani Israel only because they claim they are Jews. Jews can call themselves Jews or whatever they like but they can't claim to be children of Israel as that status was time bound and now the function given to the erstwhile Bani Israel has been given to Muhammad pbuh and his global Ummah  as a more global function which is final and biding till the day of judgement.

Comment: I understand that you have an issue with Jews; my only question -- for other readers, not mainly for you -- is whether it's on topic for *Islam's* blog.  Why does Islam care what Jews call themselves?

Comment: @MonicaCellio Muslims don't care when Jews call themselves as Jews. So yes there is no objection to anybody proclaiming to be  a Jew. *But* if you say that Jews are the Bani Israel then No Islam says Jews and Bani Israel are not the same. So the problem is not someone claiming to be Jew , but the problem is when someone claims to be Bani Israel.